# Inline if expression gives unexpected return

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I try to make it work:

```
mp = 2.5 if 'safe_mode' in options else 0.5 if 'fast_mode' in options else 1
```

But it returns `0` if both conditions are `False`, while should evaluate to `1`

Comment: What is `options`? How could it possibly assign `0` to `mp`?

Comment: After expression is executed, `mp` is `0`, `options` is obviously  list.

Comment: `in` operator works on `string, list, tuple` on all sequence object. So its not obvious to only have list as @jonrsharpe asked.

Comment: also works on `dict` (that's what I was assuming it was)

Comment: Also `set`, `frozenset`, everything in `collections`, ...

Comment: Please edit your question and include the contents of `options`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work as expected:

```
options = {1:2}
mp = 2.5 if 'safe_mode' in options else 0.5 if 'fast_mode' in options else 1
mp
> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not replicate your issue; the below test demonstrates that **in no circumstances** does `mp == 0`:

```
>>> def testing():
    for safe, fast in [(True, True), (True, False), (False, True), (False, False)]:
        options = []
        if safe:
            options.append('safe_mode')
        if fast:
            options.append('fast_mode')
        mp = 2.5 if 'safe_mode' in options else 0.5 if 'fast_mode' in options else 1
        print 'safe_mode' in options, 'fast_mode' in options, mp

>>> testing()
True True 2.5
True False 2.5
False True 0.5
False False 1
```

Answer (score 1):

WorksFormMe:

```
>>> def test(c1, c2):
...     return 1 if c1 else 2 if c2 else 3
... 
>>> test(False, False)
3
>>> test(False, True)
2
>>> test(True, False)
1
>>> test(True, True)
1
```